# How to hide line but keep data labels in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, jasper-reports, linechart

How to hide line but keep data labels in highcharts?
I have a column line chart in jaspersoft and I want to remove the line but keep the dataLabels. I tried making the width 0 and changing the color to match the background but that didn't work.

[image: Chart]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To hide the line - set the `lineWidth` as 0 & to hide markers - set the `marker.enabled` as false in the series config.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pj9Ls1uk/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.marker.enabled

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.lineWidth

Comment: Hi Sebastian, I tried adding both of those and it still didn't work. See updated pic above

Comment: @VictorUdeshi could you reproduce your issue on some online editor with the sample data?